# How to check existing user in cognito - android?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

so i have aws cognito set up in android. And i want to perform a check to see when the user enters a username, that that username doesn't already exist in my cognito pool.

Currently i have this:

```
 cognitoUser = userPool.getUser(username_ET.getText().toString());
 if(cognitoUser.getUserId().isEmpty())
 {
      //Great, this is a new user.
 }
```

But, cognitoUser just gets set to whatever i put in, it doesn't go back in check.

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try signing in with a username that doesn't exist, you will get a UserNotFoundException exception.

Comment: Yeah i already get that. At this line:  `userPool.signUpInBackground(username_ET.getText().toString(), password_ET.getText().toString(), userAttributes, null, signupCallback) ;` I tried putting a try/catch around it, but i can't log out the exception. It just runs the try and doesn't go to catch. How would you log out that exception?

Comment: all exceptions are passed through the callback (onError), you might not be able to get exceptions using a try, catch block.

Comment: this doesnt work in cases where we need to see if the user exists before prompting password. this is a workaround. Im sure there must be a simpler way. check this out http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html

Answer (score 1):

**ListUsers** now makes this much easier.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

Here is a simple .NET example:

```
        Dim userRequest = New ListUsersRequest With {
                .UserPoolId = userPoolId,
                .Filter = "username = JohnDoe"
            }
        Dim response = client.ListUsers(userRequest)
        If response.Users.Count < 1 Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return True
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
catch(Exception exception){
    if(exception.getMessage().contains("UserNotFoundException")){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer to my question is:

```
        SignUpHandler signupCallback = new SignUpHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(CognitoUser cognitoUser, boolean userConfirmed, CognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails cognitoUserCodeDeliveryDetails)
            {
                Log.d(COGNITO_REGISTER, "sign up succeeded!");

            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception exception)
            {
                Log.d(COGNITO_REGISTER, "sign up failed!");
                Log.d(COGNITO_REGISTER, exception.getMessage());

                // Sign-up failed, check exception for the cause
            }
        };
        userPool.signUpInBackground(username_ET.getText().toString(), password_ET.getText().toString(), userAttributes, null, signupCallback);
```