# Check if Users exist in two AWS Cognito Userpools by email

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

we are currently in the process of developing a platform, split in two "themes", where we use Cognito for the user system and we need to have two user pools because the user should be able to have one account for each theme.
My question is, is it possible to check if the user exist in both userpools by email without the need of passwords?
So when the user login, they would be prompted by a choice, if they have one account on each theme, to choose to login in with one of them.

The program is developed in ASP.NET CORE 2.1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check Email Already exists in AWS Cognito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083100/how-to-check-email-already-exists-in-aws-cognito)

Comment: There are many existing questions on this subject. If you've already looked at them, please add info on why they don't answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490192/how-to-check-if-user-already-exist-with-same-email-or-phone-number-while-registr
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41581107/how-to-check-existing-user-in-cognito-android